# pysqlite install error on FreeBSD in virtualenv

Tags: freebsd, python, sqlite, pip

I am trying to install pysqlite using pip under a virtualenv in FreeBSD 7.3, with 
Python version 2.6.2.
I didn't have any issues for installing other packages like Django, PIL etc. All of them I installed after activating virtualenv only.
But I get a huge error for `pip install sqlite`.
Here's the tail of the error

```
src/module.c:426: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_libversion'
src/module.c:426: warning: passing argument 1 of 'PyString_FromString' makes pointer from integer without a cast
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Command /usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/build/pysqlite/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /usr/tmp/pip-N3U6Px-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1 in /usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/build/pysqlite
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 261, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 1166, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 589, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/pip/util.py", line 612, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/build/pysqlite/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /usr/tmp/pip-N3U6Px-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1 in /usr/home/myuser/python-sites/virtpython/build/pysqlite
```

'virtpython' is my virtualenv

```
% pkg_info | grep sqlite
sqlite-2.8.17_1     An SQL database engine in a C library
sqlite3-3.6.11      An SQL database engine in a C library
```

If there is a sqlite devel package for FreeBSD, where can I find it? Or the issue is something else??

Comment: maybe you need to pass -I/usr/local/include as CPPFLAGS to gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into a similar problem, and the only solution I've found is to go into the pip build dir (/tmp/pip-{random hash}, can usually be found in the tail end of the error, may also be /usr/tmp/, or named pysqlite, depends on your setup) and alter the pysqlite setup.cfg. When downloaded it looks like this:

```
[build_ext]
#define=
#include_dirs=/usr/local/include
#library_dirs=/usr/local/lib
libraries=sqlite3
define=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
```

When I uncomment the include_dirs and library_dirs, pysqlite will install fine. The downside of this, is that I've yet to find a way to easily automate this step, so it needs to be done with every virtualenv set up. It's ugly, unpleasant, and a pain in the ass, but it does let pysqlite be installed.

Hope this helps.

PS
If you're trying to run the pip install in a virtualenv, the downloaded files are likely to be found in {virtualenv}/build/pysqlite.

Comment: Wow!!, great dude, after uncommenting those lines, and doing `python setup.py install`, It Installed !!
Thanks :)

Comment: @SusanWright: if this is still a problem for you, you might want to have a look at [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76115/5646) (not sure if it translates to FreeBSD though).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem trying to install pysqlite in a virtualenv on Debian wheezy.

I found this article:

- http://dimamoroz.com/blog/2-python-virtual-environment-ubuntu/

Which mentioned that I might need to install the dev version of `libsqlite3` on Debian to allow pysqlite to be installed in the virtualenv:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

I tried this, and suddenly pysqlite installed fine in my virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but this wont work in FreeBSD and also my env was a shared server, so no permission to install packages.
Anyways thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @VishnuKumar: ah gotcha - yup, I hadn't realised how different FreeBSD was from Debian, I'm a bit of a Unix/Linux noob.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will answer your question. This is just what I would try.

1. Try to install an earlier version of sqlite by specifying a version for example:

   ```
   pip install sqlite==2.7
   ```
2. **Try** to build sqlite from a tarball. Just to see if the problem is in your system setup. If yes, it is probably easier to debug it this way directly without `pip`. Once that's sorted out, `pip` should also be able to do it, or at least you will know that something's fishy in your pip setup.

Comment: As per the first point, i tried `pip install sqlite==2.6.2` as 2.6.3 is latest, but same error.
Then i tried `setup.py install` from the tarball but still same error.

Comment: in that case, it looks like something's wrong with the libraries in your system that `sqlite` depends on. Perhaps you can try to reinstall them if possible. Basically reinstall dependencies until everything is nice and clean. It might also be a good idea to create a completely clean VM and see if it works there.

Comment: ya thats what i too doubted. The issue is the FreeBSD server is being managed by a hosting company and i dont have root access.  
They claim that sqlite libraries are installed. Thats why i need to give them clear instructions on which package to install/reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

This works well enough.  FIrstly download and compile sqlite to your local machine (not the venv.).  `sudo pip install sqlite` should do it ironically.
Now add the below to your `~/.pydistutils.cfg`

```
## Exclusively here to allow pysqlite to compile in a venv.
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/usr/local/include
library_dirs=/usr/local/lib
```

pip inside the venv will now compile the pysqlite against the /usr/local/lib.
THis *might* break isolation - the pysqlite depends on libraries outside of the venv.  If this bothers you I am afraid the best bet is jails or LXC